# How to replicate and flatten deep nested subdirectories' names into new folder

Tags: linux, directory

---

Example
I have input directory as follows with two branches at the 2nd level (2 and 22)

```
~/input_directory/1/2/3/4/5/6

~/input_directory/1/22/3/4/5/6
```

I want to run a command to populate `~/output_directory` with a single level subdirectory set to contain (empty) subdirectories with those names,  so the single subdirectory under output_directory is simply flattened as

```
  ./1   ./2 ./22  ./3  ./4  ./5  ./6
```

The original input_directory is unchanged.

---

Using

```
find . -type d -exec echo {} \;
```

yields

```
./1
./1/2
./1/2/3
./1/2/3/4
./1/2/3/4/5
./1/2/3/4/5/6
./1/22
./1/22/3
./1/22/3/4
./1/22/3/4/5
./1/22/3/4/5/6
```

I thought this would work:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 10 -print0 | xargs -0 mkdir -p  ~/output_folder
```

but sadly not (with or without the -maxdepth which I put in there just in case).

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 10 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -al
```

correctly executes so its nearly there?

Grateful for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Danila's great answer, this is my final version.

```
find . -type d -exec echo {} \; > /tmp/tempdirs.txt; \
for dir in $(cat /tmp/tempdirs.txt); do \
  if [ ! -d ~/output_directory/${dir##*/} ]; then \
    mkdir -p ~/output_directory/${dir##*/}; \
  fi; \
done;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that's what you want as i didn't understand clearly why you want that, but you can try this

```
  [user@host ~]$ ls 1
2  22
  [user@host ~]$ ls -R 1
1:
2  22

1/2:
3

1/2/3:
4

1/2/3/4:
5

1/2/3/4/5:
6

1/2/3/4/5/6:

1/22:
3

1/22/3:
4

1/22/3/4:
5

1/22/3/4/5:
6

1/22/3/4/5/6:
```

So now try to run this:

```
 mkdir output_directory; find 1 -type d -exec echo {} \; > dirs.txt; for dir in $(cat dirs.txt); do if [ ! -d  output_directory/${dir##*/} ]; then mkdir output_directory/${dir##*/}; fi; done;

[user@host ~]$  ls output_directory/
1  2  22  3  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `basename` to just grab the last part of the path as found by `find`, outputting the results nul-separated, and use `xargs` with `replace-str` (`-I`) to append the basename onto the output directory.

```
find . -type d -exec basename -z {} \; |xargs -I {} -0 mkdir output_directory/{}
```